# Boost managed_mapped_file: setting maximum allowed memory usage

Tags: c++, boost

Is there any way to set the maximum allowed memory used by `managed_mapped_file`? For example, I have 64GB of memory and I create a 20GB file. This is all loaded into memory. Is there a way to specify to only use 1GB of memory for example? Even approximately will suffice.

EDIT: I should add I use `boost::interprocess::vector`.. maybe there is a way to specialize the allocator?

```
typedef bi::allocator<Node, bi::managed_mapped_file::segment_manager> allocator_node_t;
typedef bi::vector<Node, allocator_node_t> vector_node_t;

bi::managed_mapped_file* nodeFile = new bi::managed_mapped_file(bi::open_or_create, "nodes_m.bin", bigSize);
allocator_node_t alloc_n(nodeFile->get_segment_manager());
vector_node_t* nodes = nodeFile->find_or_construct<vector_node_t>("nodes")(alloc_n);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not such a way (portably).

Also the premise is wrong:

> For example, I have 64GB of memory and I create a 20GB file. This is all loaded into memory

**Wrong**: it will load only the pages that are used. Yes, this may mean that you might end up having the full 20GB in memory. The OS is free to do that as long as no other process requires the physical memory for other tasks.

It would be silly for the OS to arbitrarily unmap that data any reason. You **want** the OS to take advantage of available memory. Otherwise the money on those silicon chips was wasted.

> EDIT: I should add I use boost::interprocess::vector.. maybe there is a way to specialize the allocator?

Using `boost::interprocess::vector` without a custom allocator doesn't use shared memory in the first place. You need to use e.g. `boost::interprocess::allocator<T, boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file::segment_manager>` to use the mapped file in the first place.

And no, nothing in the allocator can override the OS virtual memory tuning parameters.

Nothing needs to be *specialized* (in the C++ sense of the word)

> ```
> bi::managed_mapped_file* nodeFile = new bi::managed_mapped_file(bi::open_or_create, "nodes_m.bin", bigSize);
> allocator_node_t alloc_n(nodeFile->get_segment_manager());
> vector_node_t* nodes = nodeFile->find_or_construct<vector_node_t>("nodes")(alloc_n);
> ```

Executing this code the first time around (i.e. creating "nodes_m.bin") will **not** load `bigSize`. In fact it will not even allocate `bigSize` on disk! On all systems that support it (I know of no mainstream OS that doesn't) the file is created *sparse*.

Comment: It is true, it doesn't allocate anything, but subsequently I do push enough nodes to the vector to take up bigSize. I am fine letting the OS do this, however my scenario is significantly more complex and I wanted to test the performance of the system with these vectors when it does run out of memory. Maybe there is a smarter way than running it on a machine with less memory?

Comment: Of course. On UNIXen use `ulimit`. Also related: [Release Memory Mapped Memory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24253385/85371). Oh, and: consider asking the question you actually want to ask, because this question was nowhere in the question you posed.